# Return selected value from a XML dropdown in an SQL subquery

Tags: sql-server, xml, selection, dropdown

I have a database which stores the results of forms in an XML column. Unfortunately, it also stores some extra characters at the beginning which cannot be directly parsed so I need to remove them before parsing values. Another restriction I have is that the system I use to display reports (Xtraction) only allows sub queries to be run.

Despite all of these limitations, I have a successful method to get the text values from the XML field but I cannot seem to apply it to the selected value from a dropdown. My method returns not only the selected value but all of the dropdown options as well in a non-delimited string.

As the forms are very large, I have removed everything other than the extra characters and the dropdown section of the XML below:

```
_RCFM*=.hÞ<form><select id="Dropdown01" label="Substantive APS Level:"
mandatory="true" readonly="false" style="combo" type="string" 
visible="true">EL1<option label=""/><option 
label="APS5">APS5</option><option label="APS6">APS6</option><option 
label="EL1">EL1</option></select></form>
```

The sub query I am using is :

```
(SELECT  
x.CARTITEMID
, x.DROPDOWN01
FROM (
SELECT 
    CARTITEMID
   , CAST(RIGHT(cast(cast(SVCCARTITEMM1.OPTIONS as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)),
   LEN(cast(cast(SVCCARTITEMM1.OPTIONS as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)))
   -CHARINDEX('<form>',cast(cast(SVCCARTITEMM1.OPTIONS as varbinary(max)) as varchar(max)))+1)
   AS XML).value('(/form/select[@id="Dropdown01"])[1]', 'varchar(max)')[DROPDOWN01]

FROM SVCCARTITEMM1) x
)
```

The result from the above sub query is :
EL1APS5APS6EL1

I need to return only the selected text, in this case the initial 'EL1' from the string.

Note that the code from the CAST through to the 'AS XML' is where a field reference normally would be and this is what I have used to convert and remove the leading characters mentioned.

Please help, I really have tried hard to find a solution to this rather obscure problem.

Comment: What is the datatype of `SVCCARTITEMM1.OPTIONS`?

Answer (score 1):

The value of a node is it's entire content. Try this:

```
DECLARE @x XML=
'<x>hallo1
    <a>testa</a>
   hallo2
    <b>testb</b>
   hallo3
</x>';

SELECT x.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS EntireContent
      ,x.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FirstText
      ,x.value('(./text())[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS SecondText
      ,x.value('(./a)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS DeeperNode --might use `text()` here as well
FROM @x.nodes('/x') AS A(x);
```

You did not state the column's data type. As there are *leading characters* this cannot be `XML`. Your code let's me think it is some kind of text. I think your whole query can be simplified:

```
DECLARE @YourTbl TABLE(OPTIONS NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @YourTbl VALUES
(N'_RCFM*=.hÞ<form><select id="Dropdown01" label="Substantive APS Level:"
mandatory="true" readonly="false" style="combo" type="string" 
visible="true">EL1<option label=""/><option 
label="APS5">APS5</option><option label="APS6">APS6</option><option 
label="EL1">EL1</option></select></form>');

SELECT Casted.value(N'(/form/select[@id="Dropdown01"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @YourTbl AS t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(t.OPTIONS,CHARINDEX('<',t.OPTIONS),10000) AS XML)) AS A(Casted)
```

If your column's datatype was IMAGE or TEXT (deprecated for more than 10 years, but another choice your code might point to), try this:

```
SELECT AsXML.value(N'(/form/select[@id="Dropdown01"]/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @YourTbl AS t
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(CAST(t.OPTIONS AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS VARCHAR(MAX))) AS A(AsString)
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(AsString,CHARINDEX('<',AsString),10000) AS XML)) AS B(AsXML)
```

**Attention** If the second throws an error like *invalid character*, try to use `NVARCHAR` in the first `CROSS APPLY` in the place of `AS VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `text()` node in your XQuery expression.

```
(/form/select[@id="Dropdown01"]/text())[1]
```